# How can I take the content of array

Tags: python, list, variables

I would like to know how I add the values for a few arrays which start with "yoyo" in one matrix.

The code:

```
yoyo_asd=('a','b','c')
yoyo_bsd=('asd','111','222')
matrix=[]
```

I am trying with something like this but nothing..

```
for vars in dir():
  if vars.startswith("yoyo"):
    matrix.append([vars])
```

This is my goal:

```
matrix = [
    ['a','b','c'],
    ['asd','111','222'],
]
```

Comment: What is `vars`?  What is `dir`?

Comment: Note that your variables are actually tuples and not arrays. You can cast them to list and append. matrix.append(list(vars))

Comment: @ScottHunter - [`dir`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#dir) is a built-in function

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Should be a one-liner:

```
matrix = [list(val) for key, val in globals().items() if key.startswith('yoyo')]
```

Answer (score 2):

You could just use the `vars` which returns a `dict` of the `local` namespace like:

```
>>> yoyo_asd=('a','b','c')
>>> yoyo_bsd=('asd','111','222')
>>> matrix=[]
>>> for key, val in vars().items(): # if you are want a global namespace, then use `globals()`
...   if key.startswith('yoyo'):
...     matrix.append(val)
... 
>>> matrix
[('a', 'b', 'c'), ('asd', '111', '222')]
>>>
```

> Help on built-in function vars in module builtins:
>
> vars(...)
>       vars([object]) -> dictionary
>
> ```
> Without arguments, equivalent to locals().
> With an argument, equivalent to object.__dict__.
> ```

Comment: It works too :D

Comment: Ofcourse it works. But why are you grabbing things from the global namespace like this, may i know ? :)

Answer (score 0):

Try like this what u want i would work like that.

```
yoyo_asd=('a','b','c')
yoyo_bsd=('asd','111','222')
matrix=[]
for vars in dir():
  if vars.startswith("yoyo"):
    matrix.append([i for i in vars])
```

Comment: Try it come back to me if it is having any issue

Answer (score 0):

convert tuple to list and iterate over to append to matrix.

```
matrix.append(list(yoyo_asd))
matrix.append(list(yoyo_bsd))    


>>> yoyo_asd=('a','b','c')
>>> yoyo_bsd=('asd','111','222')

>>> matrix=[]
>>> matrix.append(list(yoyo_asd))
>>> matrix.append(list(yoyo_bsd))
>>> matrix
 [['a', 'b', 'c'], ['asd', '111', '222']]
>>>
```